# Rotate and save an image

Tags: php, gd

I'm already rotating an image:

```
$filename = 'http://gabomacias.zapto.org/flecha';
$grados = $_POST["grados"];

header('Content-type: image/png');

$source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

$rotate = imagerotate($source, $grados, 0);

imagejpeg($rotate);
```

and showing it in the page,

But how can I save it so if someone rotates it again, it starts from the last rotation point and not form the original one, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [imagejpeg documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php):

> imagejpeg — Output image to browser or file

So,

```
imagejpeg($rotate, 'myimage.jpg');
```

ought to do the trick. At the top of the file, you can check to see if the `myimage.jpg` file exists using [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), and if it does, load that to rotate it again.